# How to take images from Media folder from another domain?

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 domains: [naiuma.com](https://naiuma.com) and [jp.naiuma.com](https://jp.naiuma.com).
I have uploaded all images to Media Folder on [naiuma.com](https://naiuma.com) and now I want to access them on [jp.naiuma.com](https://jp.naiuma.com).

In my models I have something like:

```
thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to ='uploads/posts/')
```

And in the settings I have:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

But of course it doesn't work since it is constructed to be used in the frames of one single domain.

Please let me know, what should I do to connect `thumbnail = models.ImageField` with the old, main [naiuma.com](https://naiuma.com) domain and it's hosting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add in project **`urls.py`**

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('your_app.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```